# Is it safe to run a dual core CPU at 68°C?

Tags: cpu, fan

I have a [Intel Core i5-7260U](https://ark.intel.com/content/www/us/en/ark/products/97539/intel-core-i5-7260u-processor-4m-cache-up-to-3-40-ghz.html) and have disabled Turbo Boost (Because I don't really need it and would produce more heat). When I do some heavy stuff like compiling a Linux kernel or running two VMs which are doing heavy stuff, the CPU temperature goes to 68°C maximum. Is it safe or will it reduce the lifetime or damage it?

```
Package id 0:  +67.0°C  (high = +100.0°C, crit = +100.0°C)
Core 0:        +66.0°C  (high = +100.0°C, crit = +100.0°C)
Core 1:        +67.0°C  (high = +100.0°C, crit = +100.0°C)
```

Comment: if the temperature is above the threshold then turbo boost won't be activated so there should be no worry

Answer (score 4):

It is safe.

The chip should be fine for its normal lifetime even if you run it 24/7 at high load and high temperatures. Just keep it below T<sub>junction</sub> (which is 100°C for that chip).

Unasked but:

1. Yes, running it at a lower temp might be a good idea if you want to run it for 20 years, or 30 years, or even longer.  But for any reasonable use (which is more in line of 10 years or less) this should not matter to 99% of the chips.
2. Changing temperatures should hurt it way more then consistently running at the same temperature.
3. Turbo should not matter here. The chip should heat up sooner. And once it has expended that spare heat capacity it should fall back to normal speed (and normal heat production and matching temperatures).

Answer (score 0):

I agree that anything below <100C is ok for home use. I always fine-tune my setups to as quiet as possible by slowing down then fans. CPU and GPU temperatures are quite hot, but never had any issues. I always trash my computers at age of roughly 10-15 years when they are still fully functional despite overclocking and overheating.

Answer (score 0):

Further down the page at the https://ark.intel.com link you cited on the first sentence of your questions you will find:

[image: Intel's specifications for the CPU]

which shows it is safe up to 100 degrees Centigrade.

Doesn't get any more authoritative than that.